# Perl command line - assume while loop around

Tags: perl, if-statement

Can anyone explain the difference in output of the two perl (using cygwin) commands below:

```
$ echo abc | perl -n -e 'if ($_ =~ /a/) {print 1;}'
```

prints :

`1`

```
$ echo abc | perl -e 'if ($_ =~ /a/) {print 1;}'
```

The first prints '1' while second one outputs blank?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-n` switch adds `while` loop around your code, so in your case `$_` is populated from standard input. In second example there is no `while` loop thus `$_` is leaved undefined.

Using Deparse you can ask perl to show how your code is parsed,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -n -e 'if ($_ =~ /a/) {print 1;}'

LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    if ($_ =~ /a/) {
        print 1;
    }
}
```

---

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'if ($_ =~ /a/) {print 1;}'

if ($_ =~ /a/) {
    print 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains. Now I have question regarding use of perl command line option -MO=Deparse you have used. According to Perl --help this option means -[mM][-]module    execute "use/no module..." before executing program. My question is, how do you know about the O and = characters in this option (-MO=Deparse). Is it documented?

Comment: @Rajeev yes, -M does that.

Comment: @Rajeev [`O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/O.html) is the module name, and `Deparse` is the function that is requested to be imported.  An alternative option would be `-MList::Util=sum`, which would important the `sum` function of [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)